# find the limits of floor function:

Tags: calculus, limits, fractions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> find the limits of floor function:
>
> $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \left\lfloor   \dfrac{x^2-2x}{\ln (1-x)}\right\rfloor $$

My Try :

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}   \dfrac{x^2-2x}{\ln (1-x)} =2 $$

but floor function is  discontinuous at $x=2$ . now what ?

Comment: Hint: Because the function $x^2-2x\over \ln(1-x)$ is $<2$ for all relevant $x$, the answer is $1$.

Comment: @user202729 how prove?

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$\log (1-x)< - x$$ for all $x\in(0,1)$ and hence by dividing the inequality with $\log(1-x)<0$ we have $$\frac{x} {\log(1-x)} > -1$$ and multiplying this by $(x-2)<0$ we get $$\frac{x^{2}-2x}{\log(1-x)}< 2-x<2$$ Since the expression $(x^{2}-2x)/\log(1-x)\to 2$ as $x\to 0^{+}$ it follows from the above inequality that as $x\to 0^{+}$ the expression under limit is equal to $1$ and therefore the desired limit is equal to $1$.

Comment: nice derivation as usual!

Comment: (+1) I didn't see your answer before I wrote mine (which I have deleted)

Comment: @robjohn: no worry! This kind of thing has happened with me too many times. For such problems there are not many nice ways to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^2-2x-2\ln(1-x).$

Thus, $$f'(x)=\frac{2x(2-x)}{1-x}>0,$$
which says $f(x)>f(0)=0$, which says
$$\frac{x^2-2x}{\ln(1-x)}<2$$ for all $0<x<1$ and our limit is equal to $1$.

Comment: This is wrong. $\ln(1-x) < 0$ for $x \in (0,1),$ so the inequality reverses. This can also be seen if you plot the original function, which is always $\le 2$.

Comment: @gammatester I fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We substitute $1-x=e^t$ so $t\to0^-$ as $x\to1^+$ then
$$\dfrac{x^2-2x}{\ln (1-x)}=\dfrac{e^{2t}-1}{t}<2$$
with $e^t>1+t$ and $t<0$. This shows the limit must be $1$.